# pdfpages remove empty page after included pdf

Tags: pdfpages, front-matter

I have a one-page `.pdf` file that I need to include in my latex document. The included pdf must be the first page of the document.
Actually I'm using the `pdfpages` package, but after the included page there is an empty page that I want to remove.

My main `.tex` file looks like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
...
\usepackage{pdfpages}


\begin{document}

\frontmatter 

\includepdf{front.pdf}  % one-page external pdf

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter  


\include{tex/intro}
\include{tex/chap1}
\include{tex/chap2}
...

\backmatter

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{reference}

\end{document}
```

My output document looks like this:

```
1. included page from external pdf --> Ok
2. empty page --> I wanna remove it!
3. Table of Content --> Ok
4. Chapters, bibliography, etc. --> Ok
```

I'm sure that I have to use some options of the `\includepdf` command, but what options?

Comment: You have a twoside layout and chapters (like the table of contents) start on odd pages. Set the page counter to zero for your front page. `\setcounter{page}{0}\includepdf{front}`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: This is just a ping to request a comment-to-answer conversion. It seems like it solved the OP's problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a twoside layout and so chapters (like the table of contents) start on odd pages. Set the page counter to zero for your front page: `\setcounter{page}{0}\includepdf{front}`